# result appending to list only as last result

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a short program to determine every combination of four dice that multiplies to make a product of 72 and it works fine if I print out the combinations that make 72 within the for loop but if I try to append it to a results list it only returns [6,6,6,6] (the last possible combination).

```
# code to determine every combination of 4 dice that multiplys to 72
# nxt function creates next possible combination eg [0, 1, 4, 6] becomes [0, 1, 5, 0]
def nxt(number):

    carry = 0
    for i in range(len(number) - 1, -1, -1):
        if i == len(number) - 1:
            number[i] += 1
            if number[i] > 6:
                carry = 1
                number[i] = 0
        else:
            number[i] += carry
            if number[i] > 6:
                carry = 1
                number[i] = 0
            else:
                carry = 0
    return number


dice = [0, 0, 0, 0]
result = []

#2400 is number of combinations possible (7^4)
for i in range(0, 2400):
    if dice[0] * dice[1] * dice[2] * dice[3] == 72:
        result.append(dice)
    dice = nxt(dice)

print(result)
```

returns an equal number of [6,6,6,6] lists as there are combinations that make 72 where as if print the result one at a time instead of appending

```
dice = [0, 0, 0, 0]
result = []

for i in range(0, 2400):
    if dice[0] * dice[1] * dice[2] * dice[3] == 72:
        print dice
    dice = nxt(dice)
```

it prints them out just fine

Comment: Do your dice have seven sides (implied by their values being in the range 0..6)? It would also mean that each has one face that's blank.

Comment: no they are six sided dice. I realised this issue but seing as x * 0 = 0 I never bothered to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the for loop. In the append to be exact. It should be:

```
result.append(dice[:])
```

What you did just copies the reference several times. Meaning all the lists inside the big list take the same value because they are essentially the same list. What I did is copy the actual value to the list, not the reference.